# Read Access table without installing drivers in Python

Tags: python, ms-access

I'm trying to read table data from Access in Python without the installation of any drivers or packages(pandas_access).

So far, I could open the current database and list the names of the tables.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
daoEngine = Dispatch('Access.Application')
db = r'PathtoExample.mdb'
daoEngine.OpenCurrentDatabase(db)
ds = daoEngine.CurrentData.AllTables
for each in ds:
    print(each.Name)
```

Is there a way to actually read each of table data and store it in a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, there is all needed operations set in DAO Engine, but I haven't heard of direct transforming of DAO Tables to dataframes as ready script

Comment: @VanNg I have tried to connect using DAO.DBEngine, I get the error ```pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)```